# Finding duplicate rows with unique keys in table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm grabbing some text data from a table and having trouble figuring out how to do this exactly.

My data is book information. I have author, book title, and a book summary. Some of the summaries were duplicated into other book titles. So, for example:

Author: David Smith
Book Title: SQL For Dummies
Summary: A great book about SQL.

Author: David Smith
Book Title: Dummies Don't Need SQL
Summary: A great book about SQL.

Author: Jim Jones
Book Title: We Don't Use SQL Here
Summary: This book says you should not use SQL.

What I'm looking for is a way to get the author, book title and summary for the duplicates and tie them to each other. So I'd see the author and book titles for both books that have a duplicate summary, grouped together.

I'm using an oracle database server.

I've wracked my brain for hours and am not sure where to look next. Thanks!

Comment: Please, provide sample data in text format or as insert statements and desired output

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from (
    select
     summary, author, title, 
     count(*) over (partition by summary) cnt
    from your_table
) 
where cnt>1
order by summary, author, title
```

Also you can use dense_rank to mark groups